# How to remove values from MySQL column

Tags: mysql

Yet again another MySQL question from me.

I have a mysql column called 'img'

By accident from a query I ran, all of the values in 'img' look like this:

```
184 2015/10/Screen-Shot-2015-10-06-at-17.36.29.png
```

I want to delete everything before the space, and just keep the file path (2015/10/Screen-Shot-2015-10-06-at-17.36.29.png).

The number isn't always "184", and further on into the table it changes into a four digit number. There is ALWAYS a space after the number.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look at [mySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) and consider `locating`the first space and keeping everything after it.  substring for the length of the string minus the first occurrence of a space.

Comment: [RIGHT(col, LENGTH(col) - LOCATE(' ', col))](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dce08/2/0)

Comment: Seems like @lad2025 did all the hard work :P

Comment: Ya might consider trying this on a copy of your table... once burned, twice shy, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy. Your query would look something like this (to remove all content before and including the space):

```
UPDATE "TABLE_NAME" SET `img` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`img`, " ", -1);
```

To see a preview what this will look like, you can run the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`img`, " ", -1) FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca try with an update of the remaning string this way 
(do a copy of the table before try)

```
update your_table
set your_column = select substr(your_column, POSITION(' ' IN your_column)+1, 256);
```

256 is for teh max lenght of the string  you want replace